# JQuery Checkbox validation on checked

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox, checked

I got an issue with a checkbox validation, I've been trying to much to create a validation with the checkboxes.

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        let x = $('#TestChecks > input[type="checkbox"]').toArray();
        $('#TestChecks').change(function() {
            $('#TestChecks > input[type="checkbox"]').each((i,v) => {
                console.log($('#TestChecks > input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length)
                    if($(x[0]).is(':checked')){
                        if(i != 0) {
                            $(x[i]).attr('checked', false)
                            $(x[i]).attr('disabled', true)
                            console.log('checked')
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(i != 0 ) { 
                            $(x[i]).attr('checked', false)
                            $(x[i]).attr('disabled', false)
                            $(x[0]).attr('disabled', true)
                            $(x[1]).attr('checked', true)  
                            console.log('unchecked')
                        } else if ($('#TestChecks > input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0) {
                            $(x[0]).attr('disabled', false)
                            $(x[0]).attr('checked', true)
                            console.log('alone')
                        } else {
                            $(x[0]).attr('disabled', false)
                            $(x[0]).attr('checked', true)
                        } 
                    }
            });
        }).trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="TestChecks">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test1" value="test1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test2" value="test2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test3" value="test3"/>
</div>
```

---

1 - I need to create a validation when the first checkbox in the array is selected, disable the rest of the checkboxes like this.
[checkboxes first checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeoEQ.png)

2 - And when the first checkbox is unchecked, I need to enable the rest of the checkboxes and select the second one like this.
[checkbox 1 disabled 2 enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x7x3.png)

3 - And when there's nothing selected I need to check the first checkbox and disable the rest of the checkboxes like in the first validation

---

any help is welcome, thanks

Comment: On your second screenshot, the first checkbox is disabled when the second one is checked?

Comment: Yes 
1 - When the first is enabled the rest should be disabled
2 - When the first get a click to be unchecked, it should disable the firts checkbox and enable the second one
3 - When there's nothing selected, check the fist checkbox and disable the rest like in the first validation

Comment: The rule 3 is broad. How can you tell nothing is selected? Nothing is selected in 60seconds? You need to specify when will the first cb be checked and disable the rest

Comment: what if the 2nd and 3rd checkbox is checked?

Comment: #3 conflicting #2

Comment: what if the 2nd checkbox is unchecked?

Answer (score 1):

someting like this???
**HTML**

```
 <div id="TestChecks">
    <input type="checkbox" class="pinus" id="test1" value="test1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="pinus" id="test2" value="test2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="pinus" id="test3" value="test3"/>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('input:checkbox.pinus').on('change', function() {
    switch($(this).attr('id')) {
            case "test1":
                  if(this.checked){
                    $("#test3").attr("disabled",true);
                    $("#test2").attr("disabled",true);
                  }else{
                    $(this).attr("disabled",true);
                    $("#test3").attr("disabled",false);
                    $("#test2").attr("disabled",false); 

                  }
                  break;
            case "test2":
                 if(!this.checked){
                      $(this).attr("disabled",false);
                      $("#test3").attr("disabled",false);
                      $("#test1").attr("disabled",false);
                      $("#test1").prop("checked",true);
                 }
                break;
           case "test3":
                 if(!this.checked){
                  $(this).attr("disabled",false);
                  $("#test2").attr("disabled",false);
                  $("#test1").attr("disabled",false);
                  $("#test1").prop("checked",true);
                  }
                 break;
    }
 });
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxwNqQ?editors=1011)

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<div id="TestChecks">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test1" value="test1" checked/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test2" value="test2" disabled/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test3" value="test3" disabled/>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#test1").on("change",function(){
    if(!this.checked){
    $(this).attr("disabled",true);
    $("#test3").attr("disabled",false);
    $("#test2").attr("disabled",false).attr("checked",true);
    }
    });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/xpvt214o/148581/)

Let me know if it works for you.